# Use Azure Notifications Hub with Firebase and iOS (not APNS)

Tags: firebase, azure, ionic-framework, azure-notificationhub

I am looking at using Azure Notifications Hub for device registrations on the backend.  I was thinking about using Firebase to handle both Android and iOS as it has the capabilities of doing that.  I am using ionic so would be using the firebase plugin.

Is it possible to send pus notifications from Azure Notifications Hub to iOS through firebase or does it have to only go through APNS?

Comment: This is clearly laid out in Apple's official documentation for [UserNotifications framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications): "For remote notifications (also known as *push notifications*), you use one of your company's servers to generate notifications, and Apple Push Notification service (APNs) handles the delivery of those notifications to the user's devices."

Comment: Thanks for the note, but that is not the question.  The question is does Azure Notifications hub know how to send to ios through FCM?  When trying to send iOS payload, you get an error if you don't have APNS configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Notification Hubs sends Android Notifications through FCM and macOS/iOS notifications through the Apple Push Notification service (APNs).

Azure Notification Hubs has not been tested sending APNS notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM); it's not a supported configuration.

If you don't mind me asking, what is it about FCM that makes you want to send Apple notifications through it? All that does is add an extra layer of complexity on top of something ANH already does quite well.

Comment: thank you much for the reply.  The issue (or rather decision to make) is that I am using Ionic/Cordova and the phonegap-plugin-push is lacking in features.  The plugin i was playing with is firebasex and it has a payload system that allows me to do more manipulation of the incoming message.

I spent a good deal of the day playing with it, and you are right... Azure seems to be doing some sort of validation on the outgoing messages and stripping nay of the apns specific data tags that FCM passes onto APNS.  

I guess i am going to be stuck dealing with both systems for the time being

Comment: Ionic 3 or 4? What features are missing from that plugin?

Comment: @JohnM.Wargo 1. We have developed an iOS Flutter App and got a registration token for this Device from FCM.
2. We register this FCM RegistrationID of a iOS Device in NotificationHub as a FCM Registration and is successfully registered. 
3. We can receive Notification push for IOS Device from Notification Hub using Platform as Android  and Payload as 
{ "notification": { "title":"Test Notification", "body":"This is a sample notification"}}
4. But when we try silent push didn't receive a push in IOS Device
{ "data" : { "data1": "fb787aa2" } }

is it still not a supported configuration?

Answer (score 1):

@AndySousa I answered your Azure Forums question on the same topic - copying the response here:

I'm trying to get a blog post published on this, but for Ionic 4 here's what I learned:

The Ionic team made a lot of changes to the framework plus released Capacitor, their alternative for Apache Cordova. Capacitor still supports Apache Cordova, but only a subset of the existing plugins. Ionic also built many common plugins into Capacitor, so you no longer ‘need’ Cordova plugins to deliver certain functionality to your app.

One example of this is the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin which adds support for registering for and processing push notifications to Capacitor. If you follow the procedure to create an Ionic 4 project, add the cordova-azure-notification-hubs plugin to it, and add the code that registers for and processes notifications like you did for Ionic 3 applications, you’ll find that your application registers successfully, but never ‘receives’ any notifications.

What’s happening is that the cordova-azure-notification-hubs plugin is properly managing the registration process with Azure Notification Hubs, but the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin intercepts all notifications that arrive on the device, circumventing the Azure Notification Hubs SDK.

This means that to automatically register for and receive notifications, your Ionic 4 application must use both plugins. The cordova-azure-notification-hubs plugin to manage automatic registration, and the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin to process them when they arrive. Special thanks to Matthew Podwysocki (Microsoft) and Mike Hartington (Ionic) for figuring this one out.

We created a sample application (https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Ionic/ionic-4) that shows how to use the plugin in an Ionic 4 app. The sample implements the same Ionic Provider for Azure Notification Hubs that manages registration, but adds additional code to use the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin to process received notifications. With that in place, it’s basically the same UI and logic as the Ionic 3 sample (updated for changes in Ionic 4).

The Capacitor Push plugin also supports a similar registration event listener you can use to grab the device push token and send it to your app backend for Azure Notification Hubs registration. Doing this eliminates the need to use the cordova-azure-notification-hubs plugin in your Capacitor application.

Note: The sample app I reference here is provided for educational purposes, we do not provide Ionic support.